# LingPipe LDA matrix representation

Tags: sparse-matrix, lda

I am trying to extract possible topics from list of tweets and LingPipe LDA seems easy to understand and well documented with code sample.

My challenge is to produce the matrix representation using tweets data. For example,

static String[] WORDS = new String[] {
    "river",  "stream",  "bank",  "money",  "loan"
};

static final int[][] DOC_WORDS = new int[][] {

```
{ 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0 },
{ 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0 },
{ 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 0 },
{ 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 }
```

}

The zero at the end of the above matrix is supposed to represent that none of the word in WORDS array is found in the content. However in this representation, it is presumed to be the zero index or the word 'river' is found.

As tweet is short, I am not sure how I can represent the matrix so that it can show the 'absence' of the word too.

Any advice or suggestion of other method is mush appreciated.

Comment: I have found a solution - instead of using the 0 to represent the absence of the word, use a smaller array. i.e., row1 now should be                       { 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4} instead of { 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0 }. With that, the algorithm will not take in "wrong" information.